# convert value from rows into column - OracleDB

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle, split

I would like to convert values from column TEXT

```
ID      TEXT
182234  ZO-Z-000-4OB-566WD1#ZO-Z-000-4OB-566WD#ZO-Z-000-4OB-566WD2#
182245  ZO-Z-000-4OB-567WD1#ZO-Z-000-4OB-567WD#
```

into separate rows (something like this, # will be delimiter)

```
    ID  TEXT
182234  ZO-Z-000-4OB-566WD1#
182234  ZO-Z-000-4OB-566WD#
182234  ZO-Z-000-4OB-566WD2#
182245  ZO-Z-000-4OB-567WD1#
182245  ZO-Z-000-4OB-567WD#
```

Oracle Database 18c

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 2):

You can use Hierarchical Query along with `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` function :

```
SELECT id, REGEXP_SUBSTR(text,'[^#]+',1,level)||'#' AS text
  FROM t
 CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(text,'#')
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
    AND PRIOR id = id;

ID      TEXT
------  ---------------------
182234  ZO-Z-000-4OB-566WD1#
182234  ZO-Z-000-4OB-566WD#
182234  ZO-Z-000-4OB-566WD2#
182245  ZO-Z-000-4OB-567WD1#
182245  ZO-Z-000-4OB-567WD#
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=54ab15f0aae5376901ddfeac64a0477e)</kbd>

Comment: Everything works. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Wait, if you are on 18c. The below is how you solve it:

```
select * from t,
lateral
(
    select REGEXP_SUBSTR(text,'[^#]+',1,level)||'#' as new_text
    from dual 
    connect by REGEXP_SUBSTR(text,'[^#]+',1,level) is not null
)
```